# Pulling several lists of data from an array where each row in the resultant data refers to the same cell in the source data

Tags: excel

I have a function that is pulling a date from a column and a time from a row where a name matches a cell in that column/row.

It pulls the data I want but it is sorting data from smallest to largest instead of matching data across columns to the referenced call.

I have figured out that it is because I'm using the "SMALL" function, however, when I remove the "SMALL" part it doesn't pull all the data. Anyone have any suggestions?

Here are my two formulas

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,SMALL(IF('MOS Schedule'!$B$5:$F$33=$B$1,ROW('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33)-MIN(ROW('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33))+1),ROWS($B$3:D3))),"")


=IFERROR(INDEX('MOS Schedule'!$B$4:$F$4,SMALL(IF('MOS Schedule'!$B$5:$F$33=$B$1,('MOS Schedule'!$B$4:$F$4)-MIN('MOS Schedule'!$B$4:$F$4)+1),ROWS($B$3:C3))),"")
```

Here's the source data:
[image: Table]

Here's the information pulled by my formulas:

[image: formula result]

Here's what's wrong:

It's sorting data smallest to largest, but I need the data to be lined up together in the results and both reference the same cell

I need the information in eac row in columns C and D to refer to the same cell on the table. I need C3 and C4 (and C5 eventually) to all refer to the same cell in the table.

What I expect to see in C3 is "1/14/19", and in D3 "15:00"
Then in C4 "1/14/19", and in D4 "15:30"  . . . etc

Comment: I think you'll need to write some VBA to loop through the source date to be able to format the second sheet the way you want it. A single routine can check the name in B2 and fill in the start and end times for that person. It can then be run to update several sheets, one for each person.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on where I can start looking for direction on that VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Column G,H, and cell I1:M4 as helper.. put in these labels :

```
I4  ---->  1
J4  ---->  2
K4  ---->  3
L4  ---->  4
M4  ---->  5
```

Insert (type in) the 1st date value (in this case is 14-Jan) in E1 cell. then these formulas :

```
I5  ---->  =IF(COUNTIF('MOS Schedule'!B5:B33,$B$1)=0,"",COUNTIF('MOS Schedule'!B5:B33,$B$1))
I6  ---->  =COUNT($I$5:OFFSET($I$5,0,I4-1))
```

and drag until column M. Then these formulas in the 1st line :

```
C4  ---->  =INDEX('MOS Schedule'!$B$4:$F$4,MATCH(1,$I$6:$M$6,0))
D4  ---->  =INDEX('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,MATCH($B$1,OFFSET('MOS Schedule'!$B$5:$B$33,0,MATCH($C4,'MOS Schedule'!$B$4:$F$4,0)-1),0))
F4  ---->  1
G4  ---->  =COUNTIF('MOS Schedule'!B5:F33,B1)
```

then :

```
C5  ---->  =IF(OR(G4=1,G4=""),"",INDEX('MOS Schedule'!$B$4:$F$4,MATCH(F4,$I$6:$M$6,0)))
D5  ---->  =IF(OR(G4=1,G4=""),"",IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,MATCH(D4,'MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,0),0,ROWS('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33)-MATCH(D4,'MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,0)+1),MATCH($B$1,OFFSET('MOS Schedule'!$B$5:$B$33,MATCH(D4,'MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,0),MATCH($C5,'MOS Schedule'!$B$4:$F$4,0)-1,ROWS('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33)-MATCH(D4,'MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,0)+1),0)),INDEX('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,MATCH($B$1,OFFSET('MOS Schedule'!$B$5:$B$33,0,MATCH($C5,'MOS Schedule'!$B$4:$F$4,0)-1),0))))
F5  ---->  =IF(OR(G4=1,G4=""),"",IFERROR(IF(MATCH($B$1,OFFSET('MOS Schedule'!$B$5:$B$33,MATCH(D5,'MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,0),MATCH(C5,'MOS Schedule'!$B$4:$F$4)-1,ROWS('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33)-MATCH(D5,'MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,0)+1),0)>0,F4,""),F4+1))
G5  ---->  =IF(G4="","",IF((G4-1)>0,G4-1,""))
```

and drag downwards.. Done.

Idea :

- "I4:M6" as "day identifier table (which day have match result)" and
  'guide' column offset.
- Use offset()+match() to 'upgrade' (find 2nd,3rd.. match in the same day) the  index()+match() function (column C,D).
- Use countif (G4) as base result counter.

Hope it helps. ( :

Comment: So, I did that. and it works. But what's the point of putting the date in E1? I did it without that and it seems to work fine. What am I not seeing? Also, there's nothing in I1, so what is the formula in J1 for?

Comment: Good note. TLDR: for the final solution, nothing. || Thanks for highlighting it.. I had used that to generate the B4:F4 values in 'MOS Schedule' Sheet.. I bring it in coz I remember using it for some of the formulas during the final formula development. || It seems like I had forwarded all reference to that cell to 'MOS Schedule'  instead. Thus, D1:M3 can be safely deleted. || Answer updated. ( :

Comment: Hello, I tried using that same set of formulas to get the data from another array in the same sheet. It worked fine for most of it but on 1/18 it only pulls some of the data. I've looked over the formula several times and can't figure out what I've done wrong. Would you look at it and see if you can spot where I made the error? https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5G2Fsv-OwMQMkJNLXFFaGNlNUxXNWVKUS1qbTljYnVnbHVv

Comment: I looked through the code again and I have discovered that the problem occurs in my new block only when the helper column is on "4". When it is on that number, it only will pull times that happen after 12:00. If I type in the "4" into the helper column at the end of the data, it will pull the missing data. I can't for the life of me figure out what I did wrong. If you try it with the names "Shannon" or "Ben" in B1, you'll see what I mean.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5G2Fsv-OwMQMkJNLXFFaGNlNUxXNWVKUS1qbTljYnVnbHVv

Comment: I just unmarked the question as answered as I have discovered a problem. The formula in D5 refers to cell C5. When that reference is in the formula will skip some information and some of the cells will return an "NA" error. If I change that reference to C4, it no longer misses the data but it now leaves off the date for the last cell.

Comment: Found the fix!

     D5  ---->  =IF(OR(G4=1,G4=""),"",IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,MATCH(D4,'MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,0),0,ROWS('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33)-MATCH(D4,'MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,0)+1),MATCH($B$1,OFFSET('MOS Schedule'!$B$5:$B$33,MATCH(D4,'MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,0),MATCH($C4,'MOS Schedule'!$B$4:$F$4,0)-1,ROWS('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33)-MATCH(D4,'MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,0)+1),0)),INDEX('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,MATCH($B$1,OFFSET('MOS Schedule'!$B$5:$B$33,0,MATCH($C5,'MOS Schedule'!$B$4:$F$4,0)-1),0))))

Comment: Sorry quite busy yesterday.. I had a look, but couldn't finish troubleshooting it.. the only error I found is in cell `D5` & `L5` where the 2nd `Match( _` should be `$C5` & `$K5` , not `$C6` & `$K6`. || Btw.. the formula you've mentioned.. I tried to put it in D5 and drag downwards, but it doesn't work. It solves the last day issue but it skips (not showing) the 1st day result. ||  It seems like the D5 need a different formula than D6.. So I've put the corrected D5 formula mentioned earlier in this comment and your corrected formula in D6. Then it works ok.

Comment: So these are the formula I've entered (based on your file) in `D5 ---> =IFNA(INDEX('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,MATCH($B$1,OFFSET('MOS Schedule'!$B$5:$B$33,0,MATCH($C6,'MOS Schedule'!$B$4:$F$4,0)-1),0)),"")` & ..

Comment: ..in  `D6 ---> =IF(OR(G5=1,G5=""),"",IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,MATCH(D5,'MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,0),0,ROWS('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33)-MATCH(D5,'MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,0)+1),MATCH($B$1,OFFSET('MOS Schedule'!$B$5:$B$33,MATCH(D5,'MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,0),MATCH($C5,'MOS Schedule'!$B$4:$F$4,0)-1,ROWS('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33)-MATCH(D5,'MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,0)+1),0)),INDEX('MOS Schedule'!$A$5:$A$33,MATCH($B$1,OFFSET('MOS Schedule'!$B$5:$B$33,0,MATCH($C6,'MOS Schedule'!$B$4:$F$4,0)-1),0))))`